# AngularJS service cannot access its own functions when used through provider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-provider

Here's my provider:

```
class testPr {
 ....
 /** @ngInject */
  $get($rootScope, $timeout, $window, FacebookService) {
    const _this = this;
    this.sdkInit($rootScope, $timeout, $window);
    FacebookService.setPermissions(this.permissions);
    const providerFunc = {
      getConfig: () => {
        return _this.config;
      },
      API_METHOD: FacebookService.API_METHOD,
      PICTURE_TYPE: FacebookService.PICTURE_TYPE,
      api: FacebookService.api,
      checkLoginStatus: FacebookService.checkLoginStatus,
      getUser: FacebookService.getUser,
      getUserPicture: FacebookService.getUserPicture,
      login: FacebookService.doLogin,
      logout: FacebookService.doLogout,
      setPermissions: FacebookService.setPermissions
    };
    angular.extend(providerFunc, FacebookService);
    return providerFunc;
  }
}
```

And here's my sample service:

```
class FacebookService {
....
 checkLoginStatus(forcelogin) {
    const _this = this;
    const deferred = this.$q.defer();
    forcelogin = (angular.isUndefined(forcelogin) || forcelogin === null) ? true : forcelogin;

    this.$window.FB.getLoginStatus(response => {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        _this.currentUserAuthResponse = response.authResponse;
        deferred.resolve(_this.currentUserAuthResponse);
      } else if (forcelogin) {
        deferred.promise = _this.doLogin();
      } else {
        deferred.reject({response: null, reason: 'Not logged in'});
      }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  }
  doLogin() {
    const _this = this;
    const deferred = this.$q.defer();
    this.$window.FB.login(
      response => {
        if (response.authResponse) {
          _this.currentUserAuthResponse = response.authResponse;
          deferred.resolve(_this.currentUserAuthResponse);
        } else {
          deferred.reject('Not authorized!');
        }
      },
      {
        scope: _this.settings.permissions
      }
    );
    return deferred.promise;
  }
....
}
```

Now, when I use the provider in my controller, everything works fine, but when `_this.doLogin()` is called from inside the service in `checkLoginStatus` function above, I get error that **doLogin** is undefined. However, if I use `_this.login()`, it works, since this function is returned through provider. How can I make the service functions access each other directly?

**Edit: I know how the scope of `this` changes in callbacks, and how to use this in such scenarios. My question is what should I use in the case mentioned in my question, as calling service methods through provider inside controller, shifts the `this` scope to that of provider's even if the service functions are called within the service itself?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Not duplicate, see the edit

Comment: I don't know if this of any help, but you are defining `_this` as a constant BEFORE declaring your doLogin function, also is this TS or JS? because it looks like you are defining you doLogin function TS way. Also, do you use `strict` or not, bacause this can affect the way things are initialized and if `this` holds the function `doLogin` when you are declaring `_this`, maybe you could check that with a console log or someting